# htaccess query string based rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Recent changes in the server software are causing tag based searches to return an internal server error. I want to correct this by using a rewrite rule based on the condition that the query string contains a tag= reference. The rewrite rule would take any url that contains the `tag=` string and rewrite it to remove the subdirectory. Here are the examples:

Incoming URL:
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/?tag=sometag

Resulting URL:
http://www.example.com/?tag=sometag

I'm guessing that my rewrite condition should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=* $
```

And the rewrite rule should be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory / [R=301,L]
```

This works in the htaccess test tool, but returns an internal server error on my server. I'm assuming that I've made an error in the condition or the rule.

Answer (score 0):

The internal error is happening because you have a space after `tag=*` and before `$`

Changing

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=.* $
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=.*$
```

should fix that error

Comment: No problem, feel free to make the answer as correct so other users who have the same problem as you will know how you solved your problem.